# How do I put data with multiple possible values in Tidy format?

Tags: data-transformation

Say I had data that had a user_id, date, and problem code recorded each time that a user makes a call. And I want to answer questions like "how many calls did the user make?" and "what problem codes were reported most frequently?"

I think I'm 90% there with something like the following:

```
ID, date, problem-code
A44, 2016-12-09, P809
A44, 2016-12-09, P810
...
A99, 2016-12-09, P809
A99, 2016-12-09, P810
```

Where each row is a phonecall record. However, let's say that first one, user A44 actually called in ONCE, and two problem codes were reported, while A99 called in twice with a single problem code each time. Something like this feels wrong:

```
ID, date, problem-code
A44, 2016-12-09, [P809, P810]
...
A99, 2016-12-09, P809
A99, 2016-12-09, P810
```

Ideas?

The best idea I have so far is to add an extra column that is "call number" as an extra variable:

```
ID, date, problem-code, call-number
A44, 2016-12-09, P809, 73
A44, 2016-12-09, P810, 73
...
A99, 2016-12-09, P809, 97
A99, 2016-12-09, P810, 98
```

Which might work, but then it breaks the each row is an observation (in the sense that it was a single phonecall). I guess the observation would be "problem code", and "call number" would be an observed value?

Comment: Since this question can be viewed as one concerning the *logical design of a database,* it should be considered on topic.  Statisticians need to know a great deal about relational databases and how to model entities appropriately with them.

Comment: @whuber this question title is quite general, but the answers are relating to the specific question only. What if there's a question with possible responses `x, y, z` and the respondent can choose any combination of them. Would each of `x, y` and `z` have their own column? Or would they be combined into one? (I'm not sure if this should be tagged on to this question - or if another should be created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadley defines [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) as data where "each variable is a column, each observation is a row." It seems like you have four relevant variables in your dataset: `ID`, `Date`, `problem-code`, and `call-number`. So your idea to gather the problem codes so that each row is a unique `ID` x `Date` x `problem-code` x `call-number` is correct **as long as** the `call-number` indexes the `ID` x `Date` x `problem-code` combinations. In fact, if you can guarantee that the user makes no more than one call in any given day, the `call-number` column is superfluous since that row would already be uniquely defined by the `ID` x `Date` x `problem-code` combination.

Comment: Users definitely call more than once per day. I'm convinced that including call-number is the correct (read tidy) way to go forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How many problem codes do you have? If you have only a few, you could use a column for each problem code, like this:

```
ID, date, P809, P810
A44, 2016-12-09, 1, 1
...
A99, 2016-12-09, 1, 0
A99, 2016-12-09, 0, 1
```

Otherwise, you should use a column that identifies the phone call. Since this will allow each call to have multiple rows, you'll need to do a bit of grouping when answering questions like "how many calls did user A44 make?".

Comment: This kind of *unnormalized* design can be recommended only when the number of problem codes is not open-ended.  A normalized structure would generally be preferable.